# *Major Season 10 Spoilers* Why Can't The Cybermen Find The Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who, cybermen

At the beginning of "The Doctor Falls" (s10, e14), the Doctor

> saves the city at the bottom level by changing the cybermen's definition of human to two hearts, thus redirecting them on him and the two Masters.

Later in the episode, two things happen of import to the question, and one in the previous episode. One of the former is that

> the patients emerge at night in the solar farm, presumably to collect children.

This means they probably used the elevators, or have been traveling a while. Either way, they are able to identify humans. The other of the former of import is that

> the cybermen have to have a lift called in order to identify the level the Time Lords are on.

But in the previous episode

> they are capable of identifying humans all the way on the first level.

Therefore, if they

> identify humans by two hearts, and they had long range sensors, why couldn't they pinpoint the only three 'humans' on board immediately? Or, for that matter, just follow the trail of broken ceilings their ship crashed through?

**Why Couldn't the Cybermen Find the Doctor?**

Comment: You wrote "_changing the cybermen's definition of human to two hearts_" I think he changed the definition to *include* those with 2 hearts not target only them. (if that's what you meant, I just misunderstood)

Comment: Did they need the lift to be called? I thought the problem was simply that calling the lift brought up a Cyberman.

Comment: @elrond The Doctor was not attempting to save himself, he was trying to save the city. As such, simply adding the two hearts wouldn't warrant the response he got. When you see shots of humans being collected, it is about 1:2 patient to human ratio. The Time Lords got a response blown way out of proportion, indicating they were the only target.

Comment: @bellerophon The Master followed that action up with a statement along the lines of ' Great, now they know where we are'.

Comment: @Imperator I'm still not sure about this, he said: "_...Computer, containing the algorithm defining human life signs. I only had time to change one detail. A single number. One to a two. One heart to two hearts. I expanded the definition of humanity._" The _"expanded"_ part implies adding something to the definition, the _one to a two_ could mean both depending on the code (_hearts <= x_ or _hearts == x_ and changing x from 1 to 2). The response maybe was caused because they were not "scheduled" to be converted as were the others.

Comment: @elrond That's very true, I was operating off misinformation, but it does not ultimately change the question; why couldn't the cybermen be able to find them, even if they were among other 'humans'?

Comment: The time dilation factor might need to be taken into account.  When they came for Bill, they were at the bottom of the ship, milennia passing for every day on the city-level.  It might have been a lot easier to pinpoint human life signs.  Also, level 507 was a farm and might not have had dedicated life signs sensors all over, like level 0, the bridge area.

Comment: I'm not sure he simply added a definition. He said that he "*Changed one detail. A single number. One to a two.*" This implies that he got into the programming and replaced a number 1 with a number 2. This would mean that the Cyberman were no longer capable of identifying beings with 1 heart as targets. Anyway, there's also the possibility that they _did_ know where he was, but took some extra time to prepare.

Comment: @starpilotsix It's possible, but if you recall when the TARDIS first lands, you see a screen that shows life signs all over the ship, so if there are scanners the bridge can read, then it's reasonable to assume these are the same scanners used by the cybermen.

Comment: I feel like this begs a further question of how did the blue man in the opening of S10E9 know they only come for humans... Much like the question of who sentenced Missy to death I fear only Moffat will ever know

Comment: Also, Cybermen are not entirely without reason or judgement.  It could be that the Doctor's 2 hearts plan DID stop them from searching for humans... but after the escape they quickly (probably only seconds from the perspective of the Doctor, regardless of how long real time) realized, 'Uh, that makes no sense, I only had one heart, must be an error' and changed it back.  Maybe they stopped specifically searching for the Time Lords and JUST continued their slow progress through the rest of the ship.

Comment: @elrond: I think the <= comparison must be right, since they recognized Bill as human even when she had less than one heart.  Following from that, we can imply a huge off-screen jump in artificial heart production to repair all of the suddenly "damaged" patients.